# Haskell defining a tree

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, definition

In haskell I can do things such as

```
a :: Int
a = 15
```

I have the datatype as below

```
data Btree a = ND | Data a |  Branch (Btree a) (Btree a) deriving (Show, Eq)
```

How can I define a tree, not using a function, such as above.

I have tried;

```
tree :: BTree
tree = Branch Btree (Branch ND Data 1) (Branch ND (Branch ND ND))
```

I cannot seem to get it to work (I am new to haskell so if this is very basic I apologise in advance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that to construct an instance of the data type you need to call one of its constructor functions. All these constructors, `ND`, `Data`, `Branch`, are just regular functions, so you should call them as such.

In your `tree`, you are mixing data types (`Btree`) with constructors, while you should only be using constructors. Also, keep in mind that the function call (the 'space operator' is left-associated) is very greedy, so `Branch ND Data 1` calls the function `Branch` with 3 arguments, rather than what you want: `Branch ND (Data 1)`.

So to create your tree of depth 2 considering the above you write:

```
tree = Branch (Branch ND (Data 1)) (Branch ND (Branch ND ND))
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that `Data 1` will be a Btree as well without any additional baggage

```
Prelude> :t (Data 1)
(Data 1) :: Num a => Btree a
```

if you want a simple branch with a right element only you can write

```
Branch ND (Data 1)
```

or two level deep as in the other answer.  At this point convenient constructor functions will be handy to minimize noise and typing.